# make a simple single instanse class as database helper

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use [floor](https://github.com/vitusortner/floor) library to use simple database in flutter

simple implementation of this library is:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  final database = await $FloorFlutterDatabase
      .databaseBuilder('flutter_database.db')
      .build();
  final dao = database.taskDao;

  runApp(FloorApp(dao));
}
```

in my implementation code, i can't access to taskDao from database. for example:

```
var dao = db.taskDao
```

my `DatabaseHelper` class:

```
class DatabaseHelper{
  static final _databaseName = "flutter_database.db";

  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static $FloorAppDatabase _database;
  static var dao;
  Future<$FloorAppDatabase> get database async{
    if(_database !=null){
      return _database;
    }
    _database = await _initDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  _initDatabase() async{
    return await $FloorAppDatabase
        .databaseBuilder(_databaseName)
        .build();
  }
}
```

`main` class to use that:

```
void main() async {
  $FloorAppDatabase db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;
  //var dao = db.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check get_it library... to get lazy singletons globally.
Also try to debug the futures from the connection to the db emulating them with Future.delayed to see if its working fine... (without the library)

Comment: which library is you are recommended it

Comment: Sorry for not including the package url, [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it)

Answer (score 0):

Using the get_it library I set up the lazy singletons async this way:

```
GetIt serviceLocator = GetIt.instance;

void init() {
  serviceLocator.registerLazySingletonAsync<AppDatabase>(() async =>
      await $FloorAppDatabase.databaseBuilder('app_database.db').build());
  serviceLocator.registerLazySingletonAsync<ExampleDao>(
      () async => (await serviceLocator.getAsync<AppDatabase>()).exampleDao);
}
```

then call service_locator.init() from the main function.